# Copy file from Windows shared folder to Unix

Tags: shell, samba, file-copy

I am totally new to Unix. I am writting a script which will copy files from a Windows shared folder to Unix.

In Windows, when I type `\\Servername.com\testfolder` in Run command I am able to see `testfolder`. The directory `testfolder` is a shared folder through the whole network.

Now I want to copy some files from that `testfolder` to a Unix machine. Which command should I use? I know the IP Address of server but I don't know the username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your UNIX server you need to `mount` the Windows share using the procedure laid out in [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-remote-windows-partition-windows-share-under-linux.html).

Basically you create a directory on your UNIX machine that is called the mount point.  You then use the `mount` command to mount the Windows share on that mount point.  Then when you go to the directory that you have created you see the files that are in the Windows share.

Answer (score 14):

With [smbclient](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smbclient.1.html) installed on the *nix machine, you don't need to mount the Windows share at all. For example, to retrieve C:\Directory\file.txt and copy it to /tmp on your Linux computer do this:

```
smbclient '//windowsserver/c$' -c 'lcd /tmp; cd Directory; get file.txt' -U administrator%password
```

See https://superuser.com/a/562728/48742 for details.  This was discussed over there.

Comment: If guest access enable, i use -U guest%

Answer (score 3):

If you can see `\Servername.com\testfolder` in Windows machine, then you can use your own username and password.

On a linux machine, you can use

sudo mount -t cifs -o username=YourWindowsLogin,password=YourWindowsPassword //Servername.com/testfolder /mnt/testfolder

`/mnt/testfolder` must exist beforehand.

Then you can copy file from `/mnt/testfolder`.

Use `sudo umount /mnt/testfolder` to unmount the folder.